# ResultSet GROUP_CONCAT não está reconhecendo os valores manipulados

Tags: java, mysql

Estou com um problema, não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Estou executando um `GROUP_CONCAT` para uma pivot table no MySQL e executando por `PREPARED STATEMENT`. Até aí tudo bem, agora quando tento recuperar o `result set` só consigo recuperar valor fixos por exemplo, string ou inteiros sem operações.

Preciso adicionar uma operação simples de soma com inteiros, o que não é possível pois os valores retornados são nulos.

Nesse caso só consigo recuperar a informação de nomeEscola, os valores manipulados `(CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED))` retornam `null`.

```
    @SQL:

SELECT nomeEscola,
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2012', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2012',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2014', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2014',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2013', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), NULL)) AS '2013'
FROM temp_graph2
GROUP BY nomeEscola

ResultSet MYSQL:

nomeEscola  2012    2014    2013
xxxxx   0,027   {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  0,109   {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,333
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,222
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,083
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,3

Recuperando o ResultSet:

final StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;");
pStmt  = conn.prepareStatement(query11.toString());
pStmt.executeUpdate();        

final StringBuffer query2 = new StringBuffer("EXECUTE stmt;");
pStmt  = conn.prepareStatement(query2.toString());
rstSet = obterResultadoDaConsulta(new Object[]{}, pStmt);    

            rstSet.beforeFirst();

            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

            while (rstSet.next()) {

              record = new ArrayList<Object>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {

                    if(i==1){
                    Object value = "'"+rstSet.getObject(i).toString().replace("\"","")+"'";
                    record.add(value);
                    }else{
                        Object value = rstSet.getObject(i);
                        record.add(value);
                    }
                }

                if (!record.contains(null)){
                al.add(record);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que pra todos os registros retornados o APROVADO e REPROVADO sempre tem um valor diferente de NULL? Lembre-se que se um deles tiver valor NULL, a conta REPROVADO/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) vai resultar em NULL.

Comment: O valor APROVADO e REPROVADO vem de uma pivot table também ,então sempre tem um valor para cada ano, e esse da execução no banco de dados:

ResultSet MYSQL:

nomeEscola  2012    2014    2013
xxxxx   0,027   {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  0,109   {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,333
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,222
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,083
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  {null}
xxxxx   {null}  {null}  0,3

Então esses são os valores  o result set no java está recebendo.

Comment: Ok, se você executar esse SQL no MySQL diretamente, todos os registros retornam valor numerico pra todas as escolas e anos?

Comment: Não, alguns anos não possuem valores.

Comment: Ok, mas não possuir valor significa exibir NULL no MySQL diretamente, correto?

Comment: Correto. O que não é um problema para o método getObject();

Comment: Entendo. Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa então. O seu problema não é no Java. O seu problema é não conseguir fazer a conta de REPROVADO/(APROVADO+REPROVADO), pois para algumas colunas o valor produzido é NULL. Retornar 0 ao invés de NULL no MySQL, seria uma opção?

Comment: Desculpa se não fui claro, mas o problema é realmente no prepared statement do java. Ou seja, se eu executar o @sql no mysql o  resultado que tenho é o que enviei, então entendendo que ao executar essa instrução no java eu deveria ter o mesmo resultado. Correto?

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, porém o problema não acontece devido alguns valores retonarem null e sim pq todos os valores dos anos retornam null. O problema deve está dentro do GROUP_CONCAT que monta essa query: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = ''',anoBase,''', (REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO)''', 0)) AS ','''',anoBase,'''')) INTO @sql FROM temp_graph2;" Deve ser alguma coisa que o resultset do java não interpreta nessa operação (REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO), pois se eu troco a coluna que vai ser selecionada para APROVADO por exemplo, eu tenho os valores no get

Comment: Mas veja bem, você trocou NULL por 0 no final do IF. Eu havia dado essa sugestão na minha resposta.

Comment: Para testar fiz isso, porém como falei não é esse o problema.
O problema é que todos os valores dos anos estão retornando vazio.

Comment: Quando você diz "O problema deve está dentro do GROUP_CONCAT que monta essa query:" ... Vc não afirma que o problema era esse, você diz que *deve*.

Answer (score 0):

pelos comentários, entendi que o objetivo é fazer a soma das colunas Ano no Java.

O erro ocorre, pois o **record** está sendo populado com um object null. Assim, a solução é testar se o que está vindo do resultset é NULL, se for então deve-se inserir 0 no **record**.

**Sugestão 1**

Diante disso, o problema relatado está aqui:

```
Object value = rstSet.getObject(i);
record.add(value);
```

E uma possível solução é essa:

```
Object value = rstSet.getObject(i);
rsSet.wasNull()?record.add(0):record.add(value);
```

Veja no JavaDoc a documentação do getObject que diz que se o resultado do SQL for NULL, um objeto null será retornado pelo getObject()

> Gets the value of the designated column in the current row of this
>   ResultSet object as an Object in the Java programming language.
>
> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java
>   object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object
>   type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for
>   built-in types specified in the JDBC specification. **If the value is an
>   SQL NULL, the driver returns a Java null.**

Fonte: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29

A parte relevante está em negrito e em tradução livre seria: "**Se o valor é um SQL NULL, então o driver JDBC retorna um Java null**".

**Sugestão 2**

Mude o seu SQL e nada mais:

```
SELECT nomeEscola,
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2012', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), 0)) AS '2012',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2014', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), 0)) AS '2014',
       MAX(IF(temp_graph2.anoBase = '2013', CAST((REPROVADO)/(APROVADO+REPROVADO) AS SIGNED), 0)) AS '2013'
FROM temp_graph2
GROUP BY nomeEscola
```

Veja que no final do IF eu troquei NULL por 0.